# How to create a preloader within a html select box using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a select box with id Provice, whenever a Province is selected within this select box, the city select box populates with the cities within the selected provinces. Now that works, what I need to know is how to add a pre-loader in the city select box while it loads the appropriate cities using JQuery

My code looks as below

```
 $('#Province').change(function() {
          $("#cities").load('cities.php');
        });
```

Comment: what you mean by pre loader? A pre loader AFAIK is something that caches the values before you need it.

Comment: cities.php is called without parameters?

Comment: @ariel - I know, but that is not the problem, the issue is the preloader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add a preloader on the begginning and hide it in the callback :

```
$('#Province').change(function() {
      $("#loading").html("<img src='images/preload.gif' />");
      $("#cities").load('cities.php', function() {
         $("#loading").hide();
      });
    });
```

Comment: @Roland : please provide some HTML, it would be easier to give a more accurate answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this,assuming that you want to add a loader to the select .

```
  $('#Province').change(function() {
             $(this).parent().append('<img  class="loading" src="/css/images/loading1.gif"/>')
              $("#cities").load('cities.php');
              $('.loading').remove();

            });
```

Comment: This works , but I need to have it displayed in the select box, where all the option values are